# reg ex exclude < and >

Tags: javascript, regex, zurb-foundation

I have been searching in futility for a regular expression that will ensure an entered string does not include < or >, that will work for use with Foundation Abide as well as HTML5 when Javascript is turned off.

I have attempted many versions of

```
[^<][a-zA-Z \'-]+[a-zA-Z \'-]+

[^<|>]([a-zA-Z \'-])+[^<|>]([a-zA-Z \'-])+

[^<][a-zA-Z \'-]+
```

etc. But I can not get this to work.

This is the current line I have:

```
    <input id="fName" name="fName" type="text" value="<?=$fName;?>" title="Non Numeric and only hyphen and single quote allowed." 
required pattern="[^<|>][a-zA-Z \'-]+[^<|>][a-zA-Z \'-]+[^<|>]" />
```

I am sure this is just a hack attempt, as I do not have much experience with reg ex.

What do I have wrong?

What I want is to allow Alpha-Numeric values(actually names allowing for 2nd etc.) with spaces, single quotes, hyphens. But I do not want to allow <sometag> this that the other thing</sometag>

The basic pattern, which works,is this:

> pattern="[a-zA-Z \'-]+[a-zA-Z0-9 \'-]+"

Now I need to modify that so tags will be flagged. (no < or >)

FYI, I have tried the Abide predefined pattern "alpha_numeric" but this allows the < and >

All  help will be appreciated.

Comment: "when Javascript is turned off"—I hope you are also stripping out HTML tags **on the server side**, because the users can change the input `pattern` attribute in the DOM and bypass the HTML5 browser-native checks, too.

Comment: The quoted pattern you have seems to work fine. Not sure about JavaScript being disabled. As @Terry indicates you would have to check this on the server side anyway

Comment: The regex in yellow text already does not allow the `<>` characters. So can you elaborate more?

Comment: Terry, this additional regex may be overkill, but yes I am cleaning all data server side as well.

Comment: MaxZoom, you would think so. However I can enter <script>tag<allowed> and not get flagged as an invalid entry

Answer (score 1):

This regex will check that there is not the `<` and `>`chars in a string:

> ^[^<>]+$

This means:

> ^ (ensure you're at the start of the string)
>   [^<>]+ (1 or more characters that are not `<` or `>`)
>   $ (ensure you reached the end of the string.

For example (in javascript),

```
/^[^<>]+$/.test("hello"); // true

/^[^<>]+$/.test("hello <strong>world</strong>"); // false
```